# GCC produces an empty _start function

Tags: c, docker, assembly, gcc, segmentation-fault

I'm running GCC Alpine 9.3.0 in Docker Desktop Community 2.4.0.0 (Docker engine 19.03.13). Every now and then, GCC will build an executable that throws a segmentation fault. The segmentation fault occurs at the very beginning of the program's execution. Whenever this happens, I just recompile the code without changing anything in it or my Makefile, and that fixes the issue.

Examining the executable with `objdump --disassemble --disassemble-zeroes --full-contents` I noticed that whenever I get a segmentation fault the `_start` and `_start_c` functions are empty:

```
0000000000001068 <_start>:
    1068:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
    106a:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
    106c:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
    106e:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
    1070:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
    1072:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
    1074:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
    1076:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
    1078:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
    107a:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
    107c:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)

000000000000107e <_start_c>:
    107e:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
    1080:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
    1082:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
    1084:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
    1086:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
    1088:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
    108a:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
    108c:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
    108e:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
    1090:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
    1092:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
    1094:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
    1096:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
    1098:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
    109a:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
    109c:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
    109e:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
    10a0:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
```

Compare that to the assembly when the executable does work:

```
0000000000001068 <_start>:
    1068:   48 31 ed                xor    %rbp,%rbp
    106b:   48 89 e7                mov    %rsp,%rdi
    106e:   48 8d 35 b3 2d 00 00    lea    0x2db3(%rip),%rsi        # 3e28 <_DYNAMIC>
    1075:   48 83 e4 f0             and    $0xfffffffffffffff0,%rsp
    1079:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  107e <_start_c>

000000000000107e <_start_c>:
    107e:   48 8b 37                mov    (%rdi),%rsi
    1081:   48 8d 57 08             lea    0x8(%rdi),%rdx
    1085:   45 31 c9                xor    %r9d,%r9d
    1088:   4c 8d 05 d1 03 00 00    lea    0x3d1(%rip),%r8        # 1460 <_fini>
    108f:   48 8d 0d 6a ff ff ff    lea    -0x96(%rip),%rcx        # 1000 <_init>
    1096:   48 8d 3d d7 01 00 00    lea    0x1d7(%rip),%rdi        # 1274 <main>
    109d:   e9 9e ff ff ff          jmpq   1040 <__libc_start_main@plt>
```

### Questions

What might be causing this? Is there a way I could prevent it?

### Update

- I tried to compile the same code on my Mac (without using Docker). I ran a script that compiled and ran the code 1000 times and it worked every single time. If I try to compile the code in Docker it fails after the fourth or fifth run (sometimes it even failed during the first try).
- I also tried to compile the same code using a Ubuntu 18.04 container with glibc 2.27 installed, but I observed the same issues as I did in Alpine, so it doesn't seem to be a MUSL or Alpine-specific problem.
- The problem does not seem to be related to GCC; I used clang 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 inside the Ubuntu Docker container and observed the same issue.
- To rule out any hardware issues I used an AWS Ubuntu 20.04.1 virtual machine to run Docker 19.03.13 on top of it and compile the same code. Here I didn't observe any issues. Therefore, it seems that the issue is somehow limited to my Macbook running Docker, but I haven't been able to prove that it's a hardware issue.

### Minimal reproducible example

I tried to reduce the code to a simpler example but for some reason then I won't have this problem (or at least I haven't seen it). So this is the smallest example that (sometimes) results in a segmentation fault:

**ex1.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void DoNothing(int x) {
    printf("I'm inside %s\n", __FUNCTION__);
    printf("%d is stored at %p\n", x, &x);
    x += 1;
    printf("x is now %d\n", x);
}

void DoSomething(int* p) {
    printf("I'm inside %s\n", __FUNCTION__);
    printf("%d is stored at %p\n", *p, p);
    *p += 1;
    printf("x is now %d\n", *p);
}

int main()
{
    int x = 101;
    int* p = &x;

    printf("%d is stored at address %p\n", x, &x);
    printf("%d is stored at address %p\n", *p, p);
    printf("%d is stored at address %p\n"
           "    which is the same as %p\n", x, p, &x);

    printf("%d is stored at %p\n", x, &x);
    DoNothing(x);
    printf("but here in %s, x is %d\n", __FUNCTION__, x);
    DoSomething(p);
    printf("now back in %s, x is %d\n", __FUNCTION__, x);

    x = 101;
    int** q = &p;

    printf("x equals %d == %d == %d\n", x, *p, **q);
    printf("x is at %p == %p == %p\n", &x, p, *q);
    printf("p equals %p == %p == %p\n", &x, p, *q);
    printf("p is at %p == %p\n", &p, q);
    printf("q equals %p == %p\n", &p, q);
    printf("q is at %p\n", &q);

    return 0;
}
```

**Makefile**

```
.PHONY: clean

CFLAGS=-Wall -Werror -Wextra -std=c99 -g
all:
    @mkdir -p build
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -o build/ex ex1.c

clean:
    rm -f build/*
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine:3.12.0

RUN apk add \
    cmake=3.17.2-r0 \
    g++=9.3.0-r2 \
    gcc=9.3.0-r2 \
    gdb=9.2-r0 \
    libc-dev=0.7.2-r3 \
    make=4.3-r0
```

**run.sh**

```sh
docker run \
    --rm \
    -i \
    -t \
    -v $(pwd):/home \
    -w '/home' \
    ccompiler:$VERSION
```

To trigger the error, I use this script that compiles the code up to 1000 times:

**keep_building.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..1000};
do
    echo $i
    make
    ./build/sample
    if [ $? -ne 0 ];
    then
        echo $i
        exit 1
    fi
    #sleep 5
done
```

Comment: Could you post the actual failing executable somewhere for analysis?

Comment: Add `-save-temps` to gcc options. Check the `ex1.s` file and the `ex1.o`. Should tell you which step the error creeps in. Since the addresses are fine, that sounds like an assembler or a linker problem.

Comment: @NateEldredge, thank you :) I've uploaded the executable to GitHub: https://github.com/MooreMachine/empty-_start.git

Comment: @Jester, thank you :) what should I look for in `ex1.s`? `ex1.o` has a chunk of NULL bytes, which I assume are `_start` and `_start_c`

Comment: `ex1.s` should have code at those labels. You could also run `gcc ex1.s` to continue the build from that step and see if that produces broken output always or randomly. I have looked at the binary you uploaded, it even has zeroes in the program header, certainly looks like linker problem. Could be faulty hardware too.

Comment: Actually you won't find the code in `ex1.s` because `_start` comes from libc.

Comment: @Jester: The code in `_start` should come from the libc startup .o files (`Scrt1.o` on my system) and be linked in, so I wouldn't expect to see anything relevant in `ex1.s` nor `ex1.o`.  I would guess either the linker is broken or `Scrt1.o` is corrupted (on disk / in memory / due to docker bugs).

Comment: @Jester, yeah, I don't have a `_start` label in the assembly file.

Comment: The addresses for `_start` and `_start_c` are still the same, so I wonder if the contents are somehow filled with zeros?  Try `--disassemble-zeroes` to not use `...` for zeros.  (x86 `00 00` is `add [rax], al`, so will definitely fault on entry to a fresh process with RAX=0)

Comment: @PeterCordes, thank you :) yeah, you're right: using `--disassemble-zeroes` I get a block of multiple `add    %al,(%rax)` instructions in `_start` and `_start_c`

Comment: Odd, only thing I noticed is that they are using MUSL as a C library. Since it appears to happen randomly have you tried a different version of Alpine Linux?

Comment: @MichaelPetch, thank you for the suggestion. I tried Ubuntu 18.04 with glibc 2.27 instead but I still have the same issue. I think it's not a MUSL issue.

Comment: @MichaelPetch, nope, it's all being written to my Macbook's SSD.

Comment: I strongly suspect it's software issue.  Bad RAM wouldn't result in the same exact problem repeating itself.  All sorts of things would randomly break.  I suspect your problem is some sort of concurrency issue, like accidentally building the same executable twice in parallel or modifying something inside and outside of the Docker container.

Comment: @RossRidge, I added a `sleep` between compilations and it seems that the longer the sleep time  (sometimes) results in more successful compilation attempts. For example, without a `sleep`, I can't seem to be able to compile the same code more than 5 times before getting an error. With a five-second sleep, I could compile the code 40 times before getting a corrupted binary file that seg faults.

Comment: @RossRidge, I don't know how it could be a problem of trying to build the executable in parallel (I don't think I'm doing that). Do you know if there's a way I could test that hypothesis? :)

Comment: @MichaelPetch, no, I'm compiling the executable sequentially, up to a thousand times.

Comment: Add a `sleep` command to your makefile and then check the process listing both inside and outside your Docker container to see if you can see multiple `sleep` commands running.  But it could potentially be a lot of things.

Answer (score 3):

The file you posted is badly corrupted. Not just `_start`, but the whole program headers table, needed to load and execute the ELF file, has been overwritten with zeros. I strongly suspect you have bad RAM, an overclocked CPU, or some other hardware fault causing this kind of corruption; there is not likely any software-level explanation for it.

Comment: Thank you! :) I ran a diagnostics tool to check if I have any RAM issues and it didn't catch anything. Also, I can't overclock my laptop so I'm guessing it can't be that. But yes, it might be a hardware issue. I'm going to try Michael Petch's suggestion to see if using a different C library does the trick.

Comment: @David: That's just going to bury the problem. If your hardware is faulty, everything you do on the machine is potentially broken in subtle ways you won't find til much later, and you should really try to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: I tested the RAM again, this time with memtest86. I let it complete 3 passes for over three hours and I couldn't find any memory issues. I'm using a MacBook so I also tried Apple Diagnostics but that didn't catch any issues either. I searched for similar tools to find CPU issues but I couldn't find anything like memtest86, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I also tried the same thing outside of Docker: I compiled the code 1000 times on Mac and it worked every single time, whereas in Docker it fails after the fourth or fifth attempt. It might be a hardware issue, but I haven't been able to show it is.

Comment: @David: Prime95 is a good CPU / cache stress test; in test mode it knows what the right answer is, and it's fairly sensitive to any bit-flips along the way.  (Or even a memory-bus stress test with larger problem sizes.)  Sometimes problems only manifest when chips are running hot, not because of one physically-bad storage cell.

Comment: Hardware issues like this can be really hard to track down and reproduce in different environments. I'm pretty sure it's a hardware issue though. We actually had a report like this a few months back in the musl IRC channel where there was a crash that didn't happen running the same program built against glibc and the user was fairly convinced that it was a bug on our side. But finally they remembered their cpu was overclocked, and it went away when they turned off the overclocking.

Comment: Whether this kind of hardware fault produces a crash or visible data corruption is **highly** dependent on the exact code being run, and really when you find code that's reproducing it fairly reliably, you should consider this getting very luck - it's a chance to find what's wrong and get it fixed rather than having it lurk and eventually ruin something important.